# Troubles with regex

Tags: regex

I can't figure out how to match this:

`[songstart]string with !@#$%^&*( and stuff[songend]`

I figured out how to match the `songstart` and `songend`, but not `[songstart]` and `[songend]`.

Any tips? =/.

Comment: You should post the regex you are trying to use.

Comment: You should also mention what language/environment you're working in. There are a lot of slightly different regex syntaxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\[songstart\].*\[songend\]`

That regex should work. See @ http://www.rubular.com/r/TtuS1CZeJf

Answer (score 0):

Are you "escaping" the brackets in your regex?

`\[songstart\]`

`[` and `]` are special characters so they need to be treated special.